# get data with json in umbraco template

Tags: jquery, umbraco, webmethod

I have the following code, for passing a parameter to a web method, and retrieving a the result in jquery ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=btnSignup.ClientID %>').click(function () {


            var dataString = JSON.stringify({
                firstName: $("#SignupFirstName").val(),
                lastName: $("#SignupLastName").val(),
                email: $("#SignupEmail").val(),
                password: $("#SignupPassword").val()
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Signup.aspx/Signup",
                data: dataString,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    // some code
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#loading').hide();

                    if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) { result = result.d; }//and some more code
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static SignupOutput Signup(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string password)
{
    // execute some code and return an object for the json
}
```

The method is not executing, I'm using nice urls. Please help, what is wrong with the code?
Thanks.

Comment: Where is the webmethod declared - a standalone .cs code-behind, page (.aspx.cs), or usercontrol (.ascx.cs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first start by throwing an `alert` inside your click function, just to make sure it's actually being hit.  Assuming that it is...

Check out [the documentation](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-base) for /Base.  Be sure not to miss the links on the right of that page, they are sort of obscure.

Basically, what I think you'll need to do is...

Move your WebMethod into a standalone class and remove the `[WebMethod]` attribute.  I've also struggled with returning objects in the past and what I've moved to is just building a json-formatted string and returning that.  So what you would end up with is something like this:

```
public class UmbracoWebMethods
{
    public static SignupOutput Signup(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string password) // you may need to change this to public static string
    {
        // execute some code and return an object for the json
    }
}
```

Add configuration to /presentation/config/restExtensions.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RestExtensions>  
  <ext assembly="YourAssembly" type="YourAssembly.UmbracoWebMethods" alias="UmbWebMethods">
    <permission method="Signup" allowAll="true" returnXml="false" />
  </ext>
</RestExtensions>
```

Obviously you'll need to tweak this a little to match your exact assembly name / namespaces.

Change the ajax call.

```
$.get("/Base/UmbWebMethods/Signup/" + $("#SignupFirstName").val()+ "/" + $("#SignupLastName").val()+ "/" + $("#SignupEmail").val() + "/" + $("#SignupPassword").val() + ".aspx",
```

Hopefully this will help you.  Good luck!